# How to add text to an existing div with jquery and div tag want to automatically increase height based on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try following codes. but this is not working. Hope you help me. 
And div tag want to automatically increase height based on text size. If any one know the answer how to add the text into div tag? Here used jQuery inside the script tag.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#new').on('click', function() {
    $('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#Content');
  });
});
```

```css
#Content {
  height: 770px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 7px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="new" value="Add Text">Addvalues</button>
<div id="Content"></div>
```

Comment: Why dont you remove the fixed height and it will do it automatically

Comment: What is happening right now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#new').on('click', function() {
    $('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#Content');
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#Content {
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 7px solid gray;
}
</style>


<input type="button" id="new" value="Add Text">Addvalues</button>
<div id="Content"></div>
<button id="getData">Edit</button><br><br>
<textarea id="edit"></textarea><button id="done">Save</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#getData").click(function(){
var data =  $('#Content').text();
$("#edit").val(data);
});
$("#done").click(function(){
$("#Content").empty();
var EditData =  $('#edit').val(); 
$("#Content").append('<p>'+EditData+'</p>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: its working fine thanks. Is it possible to edit the text what we insert in div tag?

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Comment: just only one word or all the words append to the div?

Comment: The word "Text" appended to the div tag. After that i want edit the word "Text" to "Hai text inserted successfully" or else like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you set a fixed `height` to the `#Content` element. Remove the `height` or use `min-height` instead.

And this maybe because of the demo, but in your first example you missed to insert the `jQuery` script file to your document. You need to insert the js file into your `head` element before.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#new').on('click', function() {
    $('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#Content');
  });
});
```

```css
#Content {
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 7px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="new" value="Add Text">Addvalues</button>
<div id="Content"></div>
```

Comment: its working fine thanks. Is it possible to edit the text what we insert in div tag?

Comment: What do you mean with `edit the text`? What would you like to do? @Param

Comment: I have inserted word Text into the div tag. Possible to edit the word 'Text' in the div tag?

Comment: You can change `'<p>Text</p>'` to another text, if you mean this. @Param

Comment: No I don't want to change <p>Text</p> text.I want to change after insert text in div tag.\

Comment: After click the button , word 'Text' inserted into div tag. want to edit that text in div tag

Comment: This is really breaking the question here. You should create a new question with the actual code provided and tell us what you want to do in detail. Then we could help you. It is not the right place in the comment. ;) Please close this question here with a success, if we could helped you, and create a new question then. @Param

Answer (score 2):

Set height of the div to '**auto**' and also set a 'min-height' to the div.

```
#Content {
height: auto;
min-height: 200px;
width: 70%;
background-color: white;
border: 7px solid gray;
 }
```